# Ruby CSV tab printing solution

Tags: ruby, csv, file, hash

I had a problem while printing results to a CSV file in a tab:

```
prod = { "name": "Georeous,elements,are upcoming,this year","desc":"hi"}

p = prod
File.open("file.csv","wb") do |f|
p.each do |s|
f.print "#{s["name"]}\t"
f.print "#{s["desc"]}\t"
end
end
```

In the code above, the prod hash has a name key with values separated by commas.

Because of those commas, my code is printing as

```
name       desc
Georeous   elements  are upcoming  this year     hi
```

But I want this to be printed as

```
name                                         desc
Georeous,elements,are upcoming,this year     hi
```

Comment: You're creating a tab delimited file by hand but reading it as a CSV file and wondering why the commas are being interpreted as delimiters? Am I missing something? How are you reading `file.csv`?

Comment: you are correct..but i am not reading the file...i am only writing the file

Comment: What does your code really look like? That `prod` isn't Ruby and your `p.each` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested in this question, a possible solution is to quote the cells in your generated CSV.  This should tell the spreadsheet application in which you later open the file to disregard the commas within the cells.

```
name    desc
"Georeous,elements,are upcoming,this year"  "hi"
```

Also, there were some issues with your previous code.  One issue was that prod was a Hash and not an Array, so `s` is not a Hash containing the keys "name" and "desc".

```
products = [
  {"name" => "Georeous,elements,are upcoming,this year",
   "desc" => "hi"},
  {"name" => "Rose",
   "desc" => "a rose by any other name"}
]

File.open("file.csv", "w") do |f|
  f.puts "name\tdesc"
  products.each do |product|
    f.print "\"#{product["name"]}\"\t"
    f.print "\"#{product["desc"]}\"\n"
  end
end
```